# Kubuntu 18.04 LTS - Account Details unavailable

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, system-settings, accounts

I just installed Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, fresh install, EFI boot, manual partitioning (nothing strange: a EFI boot partition, a root(/) partition and a home (/home) partition).

The system installs smoothly and I can login with my user.

However, when I enter the settings and try to access the "Account Details" panel, the module doesn't load. Instead, two error lines are shown:

```
The module Account Details is not a valid configuration module

The diagnosis is:
The desktop file settings-personalization-accountdetails.desktop does not specify a library
```

I tracked down the file `./usr/share/kservices5/settings-personalization-accountdetails.desktop` (it's the only in whole system, home included) and its content is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=SystemSettingsCategory
X-KDE-System-Settings-Category=accountdetails
X-KDE-System-Settings-Parent-Category=personalization
X-KDE-Weight=40
Icon=preferences-desktop-user

Name=Account Details
Name[ar]=تفاصيل الحساب
[all localized names until the EOF]
```

Anyone can help me understand what's the issue and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What does `settings-personalization-accountdetails.desktop` give you? I get only `/usr/share/kservices5/settings-personalization.desktop`, no `.local` file.

Comment: @DKBose I honetly don't know. I just receive that error I mentioned. Also I tracked the file down and found the same as you. I pasted its content in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that installing the backports solved the issue.